# How to deselect a checkbox using two condition/if statements (one a dropdown select and one a radio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to set this condition in a form:

If the #Size (from a dropdown selection) = 'extra-cab' AND a radio select button called 'canopy-14x-select' (from a group of radio buttons called 'Canopy') are both selected, then the checkbox with a class called .rack-kit is deselected.

I'm not sure how to nest these into each other, I've attempted it below but it isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#Size').on('change', function() {
         if (this.value == 'extra-cab') {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "canopy-14x-select") {
                    $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Should be easy.. Where is the HTML? --- Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the radio buttons share the same `[name]` attaribute and everything is in a `<form>`, reference it as `$('[name="X"]:checked')` X being the `[name]` of radio button group. This example unchecks when select is 2 and radio is 3.

```js
$('form').on('change', function(e) {
  if ($('#A').val() === '2' && $('[name="B"]:checked').val() === '3') {
    $('.D').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select id='A'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
  </select><br>

  <input name='B' type='radio' value='1'><label>1</label><br>
  <input name='B' type='radio' value='2'><label>2</label><br>
  <input name='B' type='radio' value='3'><label>3</label><br>

  <input class='D' type='checkbox'>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `change` event on a `form`? Really? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: Yep, the form knows all and sees all concerning all form controls within it. Form controls are <button>, <datalist>, <fieldset>, <input>, <label>, <legend>, <meter>, <optgroup>, <option>, <output>, <progress>, <select>, <textarea>, and <object> (object, very odd but true).

Comment: Ho... Sorry... When 3 is checked and the select changes, the checkbox gets unchecked.. sorry about this. It seems you are right.

Comment: Binding event handlers to a parent element and then delegating events to the children is called [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation). This is a common practice using JavaScript.

Comment: Basic event bubbling. Questions are a dime a dozen. Certainly there are vast numbers of duplicates to this question?

Comment: Repition is how I practice, I don't write code for a living anymore, retired.

Comment: So your practice is more important than the integrity of the site? Neat.

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne, your answer helped me fix the issue, I didn't know you could do two '&&'s (I'm still learning!). This is the code I ended up using that worked:
`$(document).on('change', 'input[name="Canopy"]', function() {
  if ($('#Size').val() === 'extra-cab' && $(this).attr("id") == 'canopy-17x-select') {
      $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
    } 
});`